# ubuntu detect my new display and I lost all around my working screen

Tags: display

I recently changed my display to a new one. (It is a tv used as monitor too.)

Ubuntu detected it correctly as a 40 inch tv. But on any program that I open, I lose the view of all edges of the screen, even on my working window. I cannot even see the Unity launcher.

For example if I open Firefox, I cannot see the top horizontal tap (file.edit, history, bookmarks, etc.), they are there, and working, but I click on them by guess.. same thing on bottom of screen and on laterals too. I cannot see the edges around them.

How can I solve this problem?  It was ok before, until my other tv suddenly broke and I bought the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting correctly, the image is stretched beyond the bounds of your TV. The menu system of you TV should have controls to adjust the position and size of the image.

Comment: Thanks you were totally right.... and I just solve the problem thanks for your help !!!

Comment: I am new here and I don't know how to mark it as solve... would you help me again? thanks

Comment: There should be a checkmark below the voting buttons on my answer. Click that.